# How can i get the variable's value from another class?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting the new variables from the adminadd class to the adminview class. I want to add the new customer to the admin view but i can't. please help guys this is my code for the two classes

```
  public class adminview {
      public void view() {
          String table[] = {
              "Account Number",
              "Account Name",
              "Balance",
              "Pin Number"
          };
          String acct[] = {
              "0123-4567-8901",
              "2345-6789-0123",
              "3456-7890-1234",
              "4567-8901-2345",
              "5678-9012-3456"
          };
          String name[] = {
              "Dina Balle",
              "Mally Gaya",
              "Toto Lee",
              "Mina Mahal",
              "Cory Pot"
          };
          int bal[] = {
              5000,
              0,
              10000,
              2500,
              10000
          };
          int pinarr[] = {
              0000,
              1111,
              2222,
              3333,
              4444,
              5555
          }; {
              System.out.print("====================FBC====================\n\nFILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION\n\n" + table[0] + "\t\t" + table[1] + "\t\t" + table[2] + "\t\t" + table[3] + "\n");
              System.out.println(acct[0] + "\t\t" + name[0] + "\t\t\t" + bal[0] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[1]);
              System.out.println(acct[1] + "\t\t" + name[1] + "\t\t\t" + bal[0] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[2]);
              System.out.println(acct[2] + "\t\t" + name[2] + "\t\t\t" + bal[2] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[3]);
              System.out.println(acct[3] + "\t\t" + name[3] + "\t\t\t" + bal[3] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[4]);
              System.out.println(acct[4] + "\t\t" + name[4] + "\t\t\t" + bal[4] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[5]);
          }
      }
  }
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class adminadd {
      public static void add() {
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          String nname;
          String nacct;
          int nbal;
          int npin;
          String table[] = {
              "Account Number",
              "Account Name",
              "Balance",
              "Pin Number"
          };
          String acct[] = {
              "0123-4567-8901",
              "2345-6789-0123",
              "3456-7890-1234",
              "4567-8901-2345",
              "5678-9012-3456"
          };
          String newaact[] = {
              ""
          };
          String name[] = {
              "Dina Balle",
              "Mally Gaya",
              "Toto Lee",
              "Mina Mahal",
              "Cory Pot"
          };
          String newname[] = {
              ""
          };
          int bal[] = {
              5000,
              0,
              10000,
              2500,
              10000
          };
          int pinarr[] = {
              0000,
              1111,
              2222,
              3333,
              4444,
              5555
          };
          System.out.print("====================FBC====================\n\nFILIPINAS BANKING CORPORATION\n");
          System.out.print("Enter New Account #: ");
          nacct = sc.nextLine();
          System.out.print("Enter New Customer: ");
          nname = sc.nextLine();
          System.out.print("Enter New Balance: ");
          nbal = sc.nextInt();
          System.out.print("Enter New Pin: ");
          npin = sc.nextInt();
          System.out.print("\n\n");
          System.out.println("Account #\t\t\tAccount Name\t\tBalance\t\t\tPin");
          System.out.println(acct[0] + "\t\t" + name[0] + "\t\t\t" + bal[0] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[1]);
          System.out.println(acct[1] + "\t\t" + name[1] + "\t\t\t" + bal[0] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[2]);
          System.out.println(acct[2] + "\t\t" + name[2] + "\t\t\t" + bal[2] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[3]);
          System.out.println(acct[3] + "\t\t" + name[3] + "\t\t\t" + bal[3] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[4]);
          System.out.println(acct[4] + "\t\t" + name[4] + "\t\t\t" + bal[4] + "\t\t\t" + pinarr[5]);
          System.out.println(nacct + "\t\t" + nname + "\t\t\t" + nbal + "\t\t\t" + npin);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I recommend to grab a good book on Java programming or read a very good online tutorial.

Comment: Hints: non-static vs. static methods, method parameters (look those up on any tutorial) - and finally: formatting and coding conventions (makes your code more readable and easier to understand).

Comment: Hint for newbies: first read about how to ask good questions here. Then: learn Java step by step. Do not write hundreds of lines of codes to implement one big feature; and then wonder why the heck it isn't working. Instead, focus on very small aspects. Implement the bare minimum that you think you need for that. Then compile, run and test your code. Then turn to the next thing on your learning agenda. Side note: you are already using arrays. You can iterate them with loops. There is really no sense in using arrays; to then manually access its elements line by line by line.

Comment: additionally this would be a good task to actually create classes instead of multiple arrays to identify your connected data...

Comment: And another note: you expect other people to spend their time helping you. So **you** should spent some time making that as easy as possible; for example by carefully formatting your code; so that it is actually easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Though not good practice, you can get a public variable from one class to another by calling it like this "class.yourvariable"

Generally, it is recommended to set instance variables to private and get them via getters and setters.

Comment: Actually, just using getters/setters is also bad practice. You see, fields represent the "inner workings" of a class. The whole idea of OO design is to **not** expose such things to the outside world. You don't "get" a counter from another object, increase that counter and then "set" the increased value. Instead, you have a method "increaseCounter" on that other class that your code calls.

Comment: True, though I can think of cases where you'd want to know the characteristics of an object and a getter works just fine for this. Isn't a get method fine then?

Comment: The underlying design principle is called "tell, don't ask"; meaning: do not "query" the state of some other object and make decisions based on that. Leave "making that decision" to that class itself. Good example: you dont do: `if (list.getSize() == 0)`; instead you do `if (list.isEmpty())` ... but of course - this is just a guideline. There are situations where getters make sense. But in my opinion, having getters should be the exception; and the "rule" would be to not have them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a getters.
If that is not possible use reflection.

I think it would be something like:

```
Object val = YourClass.class.getDeclaredField("fieldName").get(YourInstance);
```

Comment: He is a newbie; who is at a point where he does not understand how to access a field in some other class. And you advise to turn to reflection? Yes, that is like a valid answer to his question; but basically you are telling a person asking "how do I ride the bicycle to get from A to B" that he could also be riding a 100-horse-power-motorcycle instead. Not exactly ... helpful I would say.